# Regular expression to find two-digit numbers in a random string in C

Tags: c, regex, string, parsing

So here's what I want to do:
Suppose we have a .txt file with strings of random symbols inside on each line. I need to print only those lines which contain **precisely** two-digit numbers as so: 
*

- (any non-digit character or nothing) [1-9] [0-9] (any non-digit
  character or nothing)

I thought about using regex, something like this.

```
bool teststuff(char* line)
{
    int comp;
    regex_t myregex;

    // Compile the regular expression
    comp = regcomp(&myregex, "[^0-9]?[1-9][0-9][^0-9]?", REG_EXTENDED | REG_NOSUB) ;
    //([^0-9][1-9][0-9][^0-9])

    // Compare line to the regex
    return 0 == regexec(&myregex, line, NULL , NULL , NULL) ? true : false;
}
```

And it works to an extent, without filtering trivial strings like:

```
2333333|; ²³~ @`1´ ©«» ¤¼× {3} abc def ghi jkl mno pqrs tuv wxyz ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO PQRS TUV WXYZ !
```

or

```
12123asdas
```

I'm still learning C, so any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Positive lookahead should make this pretty easy `^.*(?=[1-9]\d).*`

Comment: so if a line is 12345669)^(&^(*&@3^@$, you don't want that since it's not specifically a 2 digit number? but if instead its 231234123)*&)*(&23, you do want that because it's got a 2 digit number (at the end)

Comment: @cptwonton Yes, exactly

Comment: It seems to me that you might use `"(^|[^0-9])[1-9][0-9]($|[^0-9])"`. It does not match the whole line, just finds a 2-digit number without a leading zero that is not enclosed with other digits.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's precisely what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
"(^|[^0-9])[1-9][0-9]($|[^0-9])"
```

It finds a 2-digit number without a leading zero that is not enclosed with other digits.

**Pattern details**

- `(^|[^0-9])` - start of string (`^`) or any non-digit char (`[^0-9]`)
- `[1-9]` - a digit from `1` to `9`
- `[0-9]` - any ASCII digit
- `($|[^0-9])` - end of string (`$`) or any non-digit char (`[^0-9]`)